# Как правильно брать ресурсы из Jar файлов

Tags: android, java

Есть код , который потом будет скомпилирован в Jar.

Есть ресурсы , которые этот код использует через R.*folder*.*file_name* .

Как нужно переписать код(заменить R.*folder*.*file_name*), чтобы он автоматом подхватил файлы ресурсов , которые лежат в одном с кодом Jar-e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("tt/img/update.png")
```

папка tt - лежит в корне jar архива

Comment: А если ресурсы - файлы локализации. Есть ли простое решение с ними?

Comment: да без разницы. в getResource вставляете путь до своих файлов локализации и отдаете его своему методу который будет отвечает за локализацию, прочитает его и тп.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через ClassLoader:

> InputStream inStream =
> MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(nameResource);

Соответственно nameResource должен лежать "в корне" jar-файла.